# css causing hyperlink to not work

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a website that I have been working on and all the pages are working fine except for some hyperlinks on my event registration. The first link on the page would work and then the next one would not. I created a test page that didn't have anything else on it except for the two links and the same problem happened. It has to be something with the CSS because if I use a blank master page that doesn't tie to my CSS then the links work. However, I don't have trouble with the rest of my site and I only have one master page and one CSS. Here is a link to the page. If someone can tell me what the problem, I would greatly appreciate it. I have the same issue in Chrome and IE. Browser doesn't seem to matter.

http://www.wmmpa.com/NewsEvents/event_regtest.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #footer span.shadow-bottom is set top top:-47px which is causing it to be on top of your link. I might suggest adding padding to your main content or a top margin to your footer.

Answer (score 2):

You have an [absolute positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) element covering the link:

```
<span class="shadow-bottom"></span>
```

Associated CSS:

```
#footer span.shadow-bottom {
    background: url(images/main-shadow-bottom.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    top: -46px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
}
```

Modify that `<span>`'s position so it's not overlapping with the link and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something like that but couldn't see the forest through the trees.

Comment: You're welcome - glad you got it sorted. Though not sure why you unmarked this as the correct answer?